# Change the initial directory on emacs, and also some tips for a starter

Tags: emacs

How can I change the initial directory on emacs? I started using it today and there are a lot of things to learn!

Right now I'm using M-X cd and then I change the directory that I use for C-x C-f, but in a daily work I'm going to heavily use one particular directory so I need to make the change permanent.

Also if you have some tips for a starter it will be nice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To set a default directory, simply put

```
(cd "/default/path/")
```

in your ~/.emacs file.

Emacs has a steep learning curve, but with constant use the most common commands will soon become second nature. As you discover more, emacs may become your favorite text editor, file manager, and email reader :)

To learn emacs, I'd start by pressing `C-h t` to start plowing through the excellent tutorial. Have a pad of paper beside you and write down the commands as you learn them. You'll use the crib sheet at first, but after a while, as I mentioned before, your fingers will learn the key combinations without your brain conciously intervening.

Good luck and have fun!

Comment: thanks!, i suppose this line is in Lisp, is really a necessity learning lisp to get full advantage of Emacs? i have already add a couple of lines in .emacs to get work Auctex, and i really don't understand em very well, just copy paste by instruction, :)

Comment: First you may copy and paste, and little by little you'll understand what it means. To use emacs, you don't need to know Lisp. But eventually, you may find it convenient to extend emacs' functionality with macros. At that point you'll want to learn elisp.

Comment: It is indeed necessary to learn lisp to get the full advantage of emacs.  You can nevertheless use it effectively without learning lisp.

Answer (score 3):

Default directory is determined by:

```
(setq default-directory "~/")
```

in this case, set to the users home dir, but it could be somewhere else.

If this variable is not set, the initial load point for find-file will be the directory where the emacs executable lives.

EDIT: on windows, a global HOME environment variable can be defined (HOME=c:\path\to\user\home\directory), ensuring that Emacs translates ~ to the correct value. This makes the Emacs settings usable across platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Start up emacs only after changing to that "initial directory", effectively setting the *current directory* for emacs.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution specific to Windows.

1. Create a shortcut to `emacs.exe"` called **GNU Emacs**
2. Open Properties on the **GNU Emacs** shortcut
3. Set **Start in** to `%USERPROFILE%\Documents`

This solution works for multi-user workstations whether they are on or off Active Directory.

This shortcut will start Emacs in the current user's Documents folder.

Comment: This is the only one that seems to work on Windows - all of the others the first CTRL-X-f starts in the original location

Answer (score 0):

Print out the Gnu Emacs Reference card and keep it by the desk.

Comment: I would say make your own reference card!!  The gnu emacs ref card is useful, but I found that it has a lot of stuff I don't need, and it doesn't have a lot of stuff I need :)